# Qlik compare average by dimension compared to average of first dimension

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Background:

> I have a list of scores for a number of questions and I have split my
>   participants into generation groups.

I am trying to compare the average score for each question, with the average for the generation. My current (failing) script is as below.

```
if(Generation = 'Boomers2'
  ,(Avg(Score)-Avg({<Generation = {"Boomers2"}>} Score))
      ,if(Generation = 'Generation X'
          ,(Avg(Score)-Avg({<Generation = {"Generation X"}>} Score))
          ,(Avg(Score)-Avg({<Generation = {"Millenials"}>} Score))
      )
)
```

I'm sure I could do this with some ETL - ideally I'm looking to do this using `set analysis` but will accept either answer. For reference, here is my load script.

```
SurveyRaw:
LOAD 
    [F1] as RowID,
    Timestamp(Timestamp#([A], 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss') ) AS [EntryDate],
    [B] AS [YearOfBirth],
    [C] AS [PerceivedGeneration],
    [D] AS [AbilityToAdapt],
    [E] AS [TeamWork],
    [F] AS [ProblemSolving],
    [G] AS [Collaboration],
    [H] AS [Entrepreneurial],
    [I] AS [Overtime],
    [J] AS [Collaboration2],
    [M] AS [FutureQuestion]
 FROM [lib://workingstyles]
(html, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, table is @1)
where IsNum([B]) and [B]<1998; //and [B]>=1966;

Scores:
CrossTable(Question, Score)
Load RowID, [AbilityToAdapt],[TeamWork],[ProblemSolving],[Collaboration],[Entrepreneurial],[Overtime],[Collaboration2]
Resident SurveyRaw;

Load Question, Avg(Score) as AvgQuestionScore
Resident Scores
Group By Question;

Left Join (SurveyRaw)
Load Sum(Score) as TotalScore
,Sum(Score)/7 as AvgUserScore
,RowID
Resident Scores Group By RowID;

Drop Fields [AbilityToAdapt],[TeamWork],[ProblemSolving],[Collaboration],[Entrepreneurial],[Overtime],[Collaboration2] From [SurveyRaw];

Generations:
Load * Inline
[Year_Start, Year_End, Generation
1946, 1954, Boomers1
1955, 1965, Boomers2
1966, 1976, Generation X
1977, 1994, Millenials
1995, 2012, Z];

IntervalMatch:
IntervalMatch([YearOfBirth])
Load     Distinct Year_Start,Year_End 
Resident Generations;
```

Comment: wouldn't it be something like  "Avg({1} Score)- Avg(Score)"

Comment: @Kostya `Avg({1} Score)` gives me the overall average, I'm looking to compare the average for the generation instead

Answer (score 0):

if you can assign an INT value to your Generation, you could do something like

```
=Avg(Score)- avg({<Generation ={$(=Generation-1)}>} Score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 master dimensions based on calculated field, one with set analysis to calculate avg per generation and one for total average over all selections. Doing it in the load script will make it faster.